# After migration to storybook V7, I can't run

Tags: storybook

In my project, after migration to storybookV7 with `pnpm dlx storybook@latest upgrade`
according this docs https://storybook.js.org/docs/7.0/migration-guide.

After that, I tried to run with `storybook dev -p 6006`.
Then an error occur↓

````
=\> Failed to build the preview
99% end closing watch compilationWARN Force closed preview build
SB_BUILDER-WEBPACK5_0003 (WebpackCompilationError): There were problems when compiling your code with Webpack.
Run Storybook with --debug-webpack for more information.
at starter (./node_modules/.pnpm/@storybook+builder-webpack5@7.6.7_esbuild@0.18.20_typescript@5.3.2/node_modules/@storybook/builder-webpack5/dist/index.js:1:9660)
at starter.next (\<anonymous\>)
at Module.start (./node_modules/.pnpm/@storybook+builder-webpack5@7.6.7_esbuild@0.18.20_typescript@5.3.2/node_modules/@storybook/builder-webpack5/dist/index.js:1:11692)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

WARN Broken build, fix the error above.
WARN You may need to refresh the browser.```
````

When I execute `storybook dev -p 6006`, at the beginning storybook can be opened on browser, but a moment later, above error occur. I have no idea.

git reset --hard and execute
`pnpm dlx storybook@latest upgrade`

Answer (score 0):

install `@storybook/cli` make sure its the exact version of the storybook you upgraded to.

Then replace the following scripts in your package.json

````
    "storybook": "sb dev",
    "build-storybook": "sb build"```
````